# Can't open file in java-eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse

I am just starting off in Java and trying to follow buckythenewboston on you tube. I have java and eclipse neon both downloaded correctly. However, when I create a new project like he showed in the video, I click finish and nothing shows up, in the video it showed on the side there should be a like java symbol with the name of the project I created. Well nothing happens it is blank on my screen. I tried opening a file from the work space in my C drive and that doesn't work either as nothing shows up so I can create a class. I know there is a couple of forum questions with similar title but that is different I think as they can at least get code in where I can't. Any explanation as what is going on would be helpful. I also tried to go to file-import-existing project... but the existing project part isn't an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any images? We can not guest your problem. But I think you should try to download eclipse again :)

Comment: sounds like an eclipse issue. have you tried going to your workspace directory and deleting `.metadata` folder, then restarting eclipse?

Comment: Thanks Bill, your suggestion worked. Thanks so much. So um should I delete this thread or wait till Bill uploads an official answer and like and stuff to his answer?

Comment: it's all good, you can delete if you want. or leave it for the next guy who has the same issue.

Comment: I will leave it for the next guy who has the same issue. Thanks again. Glad it was a simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go into your workspace directory and delete `.metadata` folder, then restart eclipse

Comment: Looks like this deletes all the info about the projects and does not solve the problem

Comment: It worked for Bob's issue. Are you having the same problem?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but my point is that although this might solve the problem, it will delete possibly important information about your project.

Answer (score 2):

Close all perspectives and open a new one, the one you like.